# What is the correct way of loading NumPy images from npy file into a PyTorch tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

The following code loads a bunch of images (the Kaggle cats and dogs dataset) and stores those into a npy file. The file can then be loaded for further processing, which in my case is converting the data inside to PyTorch tensors and iterating over it using the PyTorch `DataLoader`.

**Note:** All images are loaded from JPG files as grayscale (`uint8`) and resized (see `img_size` class member)

```
class DataLoaderRaw():
    img_size = 50
    cats = 'PetImages/Cat'
    dogs = 'PetImages/Dog'
    pet_labels = {cats: 0, dogs: 1}
    data = []
    catcount = 0
    dogcount = 0


    def make_training_data(self):
        for pet_label in self.pet_labels:
            print('Loading pet data from', pet_label)

            for img_path in os.listdir(pet_label): # tqdm(...)
                pet_img_path = os.path.join(pet_label, img_path)
                try:    
                    pet_img = cv2.imread(pet_img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                    pet_img = cv2.resize(pet_img, (self.img_size, self.img_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

                    self.data.append([np.array(pet_img), np.eye(2)[self.pet_labels[pet_label]]])

                    if pet_label == self.cats:
                        self.catcount += 1
                    elif pet_label == self.dogs:
                        self.dogcount += 1

                except Exception as ex:
                    pass
                    #print('Failed to load', pet_img_path)

        self.data = np.array(self.data)
        np.random.shuffle(self.data)
        np.save('data.npy', self.data)        
        print('Dataset statistics:')
        print('Total samples:', len(self.data))
        print('Cat samples:', self.catcount)
        print('Dog samples:', self.dogcount)

    def from_np_file(path='data.npy'):
        data = np.load(path, allow_pickle=True)
        dlr = DataLoaderRaw()
        dlr.data = data
        return dlr

rebuild_data = False

if rebuild_data:
    print('Rebuilding data')
    dlr = DataLoaderRaw()
    dlr.make_training_data()
else:
    print('Loading data')
    dlr = DataLoaderRaw.from_np_file('data.npy')
```

Simply doing

```
data = torch.from_numpy(dlr.data)
```

yields

> TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_. The only supported types are: float64, float32, float16, complex64, complex128, int64, int32, int16, int8, uint8, and bool.

I tried doing

```
data = torch.Tensor([torch.from_numpy(img[0]) for img in dlr.data])
```

where the first element of every element `img` is the large array that contains the pixel data, but I get a warning

> Creating a tensor from a list of numpy.ndarrays is extremely slow. Please consider converting the list to a single numpy.ndarray with numpy.array() before converting to a tensor.

Printing the type of `dlr.data` yields `object`. And here is the first element so that you can get some perspective on what's inside:

```
[[array([[127, 137, 186, ...,  39,  36,  31],
         [127, 132, 166, ...,  31,  32,  38],
         [220, 207, 195, ...,  28,  40,  40],
         ...,
         [117, 115, 120, ..., 110,  30,  22],
         [113, 104, 110, ..., 184,  36,  26],
         [127, 129, 130, ..., 184,  27,  29]], dtype=uint8)
  array([1., 0.])]
  ...
]]
```

What is the correct way of loading NumPy images from npy file into a PyTorch tensor?

Comment: `dlr.data` is probably object dtype, and 1d.  Each element of the array is an object, probably an array.  The fact that it isn't a 2d numeric dtype array, means those component arrays vary in shape.  You can't make a `tensor` from such array.  Examine the component shapes.  You may need to resize the images.

Comment: I updated my question. Yes, it is `object` (as `print(type(dlr.data))` states). As for the shapes - those should be the same since every image is resized (50x50 using OpenCV and the `img_size` variable) and the respective image label (1x2 created from `np.eye(2)[...]`). Is it possible that the saving to and loading from the npy file has done this conversion of types?

Comment: You probably want to use `torchvision.transforms`. There is a `ToTensor()` transform that takes care of many things for you, such as `dtype`.

Comment: You show a 2 element array containing a (n,m) `uint8` array and a (2,) float array.  That may be the image and some sort of `label`.  You can't make a `tensor` from that.  You should be able to combine the `image` parts, and the labels parts into separate `xdata` and `ydata` arrays/tensors.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, each element consists of image + label (see `np.eye(2)`). I did separate the two using `images = torch.Tensor([i[0] for i in dlr.data]).view(-1, 50, 50)` (the `view` is to bring it into a form suitable for the network, added extra normalization after that `images = images/255.0`) and `labels = torch.Tensor([i[1] for i in dlr.data])` for the labels. But that is the part where I get the complaint that it's slow. Perhaps I should just save the labels in one NPY and the images in another? I'm not familiar with the general practice here.

Comment: Yes keep them separate.  Though I've also seen people extract them from one array, e.g. `xdata = data[:,:-1]` and `ydata = data[:,-1]`.  That is labels is the last column of a 2d array.

Comment: @hpaulj The problem with keeping labels from images separate is that shuffling is more complicated since the two need to be processed in unison. Otherwise the result will be mismatched labels and images. Such a step will also require copying the contents of the two (at least this is what I think) into a single array (for the shuffling), which - given a large dataset - can become a big problem in terms of resources.